# SDL drawing a sprite once a button is pressed

Tags: c++, sdl, sprite

So, i'm a complete stranger to SDL and i found this nice code online:
http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/animating-sprites-with-sdl/

I was just wondering how to make it so that when i press space a shape gets placed infront of me? For instance, im just walking around and when i press space a rectangle or another bmp is places in front of me.

Sorry for not being explicit in what i want, i just dont know how to explain it.

Comment: Can you post the code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

- Another Surface to draw (blit), made from the rectangle.bmp. This would use the same method as is used for the grass (or the player if you wanted animation).
- Knowledge of where "in front" is: up, down, left or right. Look at the code and see what variables change when you press one of the arrow keys. (Hint: don't use rcSprite.) In a larger game, you would want to define a new variable for the direction that the player is facing, and then use that for both the sprite animation and for placing the rectangle, as it would make the code easier to understand.
- Some new code in HandleEvent, which does something if the key is SDLK_SPACE.

Then calculate a position to place the rectangle (say, the player's position with 50 added to "x" if they were facing right), and draw the rectangle in the same way as the grass.

---

In general, look at what code has already been written, and Google for stuff you don't know (e.g. the name of SDLK_SPACE).

Good luck